What number appears most often in an $n \times n$ multiplication table and How many times does it appear?
Recently, I have considered a problem:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{a_{n,k}}{n^2}X_{k} \stackrel{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}  ?$$
where
$$a_{n,k} = \#\left\{(i,j) \mid ij = k, i, j \in [n]\right\}$$
and ${X_{k}}$ is i.i.d random variables with mean zero and finite variance. I have refered to some articles about "The Strong Law of Large Numbers For Weighted Sums of Arrays of Random Variables" The problem converts to if there is a positive $\gamma$ such that:
$$max_{1 \leq k \leq n^{2}} |a_{n,k}|=\mathcal{O}(n^{\gamma})$$
This is the problem stated in the title, I find that there is a related problem has been posted in 2014:
What number appears most often in an $n \times n$ multiplication table? I am curious about is there some progress on it.
